# Chosing directory to save item images in e-commerce shop

Tags: image-uploading, directory-structure

I always see that when building something like e-commerce web shop people handle pictures like this: They put picture of item in folder `pictures/xxxx/picture_name.jpg` where xxxx is an id of our item.

But right now I just save pictures to `pictures` folder without subfolder.
I will have in total nearly 10 000 items in my web shop. So I wonder will putting images in separate folders increase performance of my website or not really?

I am using Rails. But this is question not really related to certain languages or frameworks. I know that I can test it, but I don't have 10 000 items yet, so I can't really say will performance change or not.

Comment: @halfer you are right) I will remove my rollback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a folder structure such as `pictures/xxxx/picture_name.jpg` will not make it faster to *display* an image. It will, however, be much easier to manually find images as the system grows -- so your data is easier to maintain.

Defining the folder structure is fairly straight forward. For example if you're using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) in your Rails application then [defining a custom folder structure](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory) is simply a matter of overloading one method.
For instance, here's a generic folder structure that you may wish to use:

```
  def store_dir 
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}" 
  end
```

However, not all files in your system will be uploaded through the interface. Have a read through the Rails tutorials on the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html); understand the difference in usage between the `app/assets`, `vendor/assets` and `public/` folders. A proper understanding and use of the framework here *will* greatly improve the application performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So is it better to include item pictures in app/assets or public folder?

Comment: It depends what the file is. The short answer is that `'app/assets/*'` uses the asset pipeline and `'public/*'` is simply for static files. There is a time and place for both.

Answer (score 0):

> So I wonder will putting images in separate folders increasy
>   performance of my website or not really?

It depends on the filesystem. It will definitely slow down a search of a file by name in ext2/3/4 if you turn dir_index option off and have many thousands of files there.

Although with modern file systems it could be no problem putting hundred thousands of file per one directory, it increases maintenance cost of such a solution. If you will need to make something by hand, you will be unable to use simple `ls` to see what your folder has. Tools like mc could suffer from some limitations displaying a sorted list of files in a folder.

In other words, it is possible in most cases to store all pictures inside a single folder, but it is impractical.